# AppCenter Rejection - missing (NOT) SSO

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, facebook-app-center

I have a problem with App Center Review. I have an iOS application which has the Single Sign-On implemented (I just tested it on both types of devices). Still, when I submit my app's page for App Center Review I always get the same message (see screenshot below).

[image: Message from App Center Review team]

I don't know what to do anymore. It has been like this for at least few months now. I checked everything in my application, even was able to post an update in the meantime, and the page still get's rejected. The message is always the same so I don't get any more info about the error (which in my opinion does not exists).

What should I do with this issue? Who can I contact directly about it (via email preferably)?

Edit #1: In my opinion I am using the native login screen. I am 100% sure that I use official FB API (downloaded from FB page). When I connect with FB in my application the screen that pops up is a screen from FB application (see below).

[image: Facebook screen]

Edit #2: Okay, so I've implemented new way of logging in with FB but still native login view is not presented. Instead, the login screen of FB application opens up, which is exactly the same behaviour as before... I have the FacebookDisplayName set in the .plist file.

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"some_facebook_app_id"];
[FBSettings setDefaultUrlSchemeSuffix:@"some_suffix"];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"] allowLoginUI:TRUE completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

 // handler logic goes here

}];
```

Edit #3: yeap, the new API was **the solution**. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the native Login dialog that comes with Facebook's SDK for login?

Comment: I think so, yes. Please check my edit for the initial post.

Comment: Can't tell, I don't use Facebook. :-)

Comment: You can check by comparing your implementation to this example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/

Comment: You are right, I was still using the old Api. I've downloaded new API but am unable to get the Native Login View to show up. Can check see "Edit #2"? Maybe an idea of what is wrong will popup?